# Do the Nickelodeon TV shows "Sam & Cat" and "iCarly" take place in the same universe?

Tags: analysis, icarly, sam-and-cat

I was watching *Sam & Cat* on tv then *iCarly* was on next so I watched an episode of that to see how it was like and the Sam in *iCarly* had the same name as the one in *Sam & Cat* so I was wondering if they were the same character and the two shows take place in the same place or if there was just a reference...

Answer (score 2):

*Sam & Cat* is a [spinoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-off_(media)) of *iCarly*, so yes, they take place in the same world.

From the Wikipedia page:

> Sam & Cat is an American teen sitcom that originally aired from June 8, 2013, to July 17, 2014, on Nickelodeon. It is a crossover spin-off/sequel of both iCarly and [Victorious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victorious). It stars Jennette McCurdy as Sam Puckett and Ariana Grande as Cat Valentine.